# Passing an array with an unknown size to a function

Tags: php

I've been scouring Google for an answer to this problem I'm having and have come up empty so far.

Basically, I'm creating an array of error messages, passing them as an array to a function, looping through the values, formatting and then returning them. For some reason the values do not get passed and I get an "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" error.

```
//Create the error array
$error = 0;
$errorArray = array();
if(empty($_POST['amount']))
{
    $error = 1;
    array_push($errorArray,"Amount is required");
}

//Error Function
function makeErrors($err)
{
    $output = 'ul'; 
    foreach($err as $v)
    {
        $output .= '<li>'.$v.'</li>';
    }
    $output .= '</ul>';
    return $output;
}

//Show the result
if($error == 1)
{
    $theErrors = makeErrors($errorArray);
    echo $theErrors;
}
```

If I just do a plain old print_r on $errorArray I get the expected value, so there's something lost when passing the array to the function. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me, I've just tried with cut&paste!

Comment: I also dont see any obvious mistake, did you try passing the array as reference? By the way, should your first ul not be <ul>?

Comment: do a `var_dump` instead..`print_r` will get you a result even if the value is not array

Comment: also do `var_dump($err)` inside the function to see whats actually passed in as `$err`

Comment: your question's title implies you think the problem is with not knowing the array's size in advance. I this was required writing anything beyond Hello World would be a little tricky!

Comment: The code did work fine, var_dump results were as expected. Turns out the problem was where I was calling the function in the actual page. I was calling the function in the error div just above the actual form which calls the validation script and sets $errorArray. Basically the array didn't exist yet. Weak sauce, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work perfectly, you might want to wrap the first "ul" in <> though.

Just tested it and its working fine here.

Comment: Probably he is just looking at the page and not at the source so he does not see the code because the ul is set wrong.

Comment: Maybe; I would imagine that it is more likely that he is just printing an empty array with print_r though.

Comment: Well the print_r was for debugging but in his actual code you see the echo. But in the end that does not matter at all, I think the problem originates from the <> issue with ul but as long as the OP does not say something more about it we can only guess.

Comment: The ul issue was just a typo on my behalf when I submitted the question, it was actually <ul> in my code. See comments above...solved the problem, it was a rookie mistake.

Comment: I actually had the include file with the error handling in the wrong spot so it was being passed an empty variable...my bad.